# How can I choose a value depending on another value without IF (multiple values)

Tags: excel

i will explain better becuase the question is not the best. Lest say I have a table,called `table1` with 10 Columns and 100 rows. Then, on a new column I generate Random values from the first column of `table1` (using index and randBetween). What I want to do, is then generate 9 columns more which will need to match each row of the `table1` depending on the first column. Example.

```
Table1
    ID Name Age
    1  Jhon 35
    2  Maria 70
    3  Robert 85
```

So, on a new table, if I generate ID 3, then how to do that next columns are Robert and 85? I hope I explained it properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the generated id is in `Cell E2`, then in `Cell F2` enter the following formula

```
=VLOOKUP(E2,$A$2:$C$4,2)
```

In `Cell G2` enter the following formula

```
=VLOOKUP(E2,$A$2:$C$4,3)
```

See image for reference

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I found it by myself  using `lookup`. Is there any difference between that and `vlookup` ?

Comment: @Lomezno - The main difference is `LOOKUP` works on sorted data while `VLOOKUP` can find an exact match on unsorted data. For the other differences see [this](http://whatisdifferencebetween.net/computer/program/difference-between-lookup-and-vlookup-lookup-vs-vlookup/) and [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-main-difference-between-Excel-LOOKUP-and-VLOOKUP).

Comment: @Lomezno - You can also use just one formula like `=VLOOKUP($E3,$A$2:$C$4,COLUMN()-4)` and drag across to get results for other 9 columns (you'll have to change `COLUMN()-4` as per your columns).

Comment: Thanks, I know about draging and dropping :D

Answer (score 0):

Use [a `VLOOKUP` formula](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) on your new table in the 9 rows.

Below, I have put in the raw value `3` but you should use a reference to your new table. I have assumed your old table is in columns `A:C`. `2` is the column to return; replace with `3-9` as needed. `FALSE` ensures you only get exact matches.

```
=VLOOKUP(3,A:C,2,FALSE)
```

For a cleaner sheet, I tend to wrap in an `IFNA` so that cells are blank when there is no match, instead of have `#N/A`

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(3,A:C,2,FALSE),"")
```